# List Sorting for treeview via linq

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have A list

```
key ParentKey
1   Null
2   1
3   Null
4   Null
5   1
6   4
7   6
8   3
```

I want it sorted in

```
key ParentKey
1   Null
2   1
5   1
3   Null
8   3
4   Null
6   4
7   6
```

via linq how can this be done?
Any help is most wellcome

Comment: Please can you explain what have you tried?

Comment: I dont have any idea how start even...I can use a loop to get the work done but i want to do it via linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the result should be:

```
key ParentKey
1   Null
2   1
5   1
3   Null
8   3
4   Null
6   4
7   6
```

I can say that you can't do anything if there isn't a logic that make the null values in that position into the list.

So using Linq you can order the list using the [OrderBy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb534966.aspx) function:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.ParentKey).ToList();
```

But using this function the result is the following:

```
key ParentKey
1   Null
3   Null
4   Null
2   1
5   1
8   3
6   4
7   6
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have a list of

```
public class MyObject{
      int Key {get;set;}
      int ? ParentKey{get;set;}
}
```

then for sorting this list use :

```
 var list = new List<MyObject>(){ new MyObject{ Key = 1 , ParentKey = null } , new MyObject{Key=2 , PatentKey = 1}  /* and so on */};

  var sortedList = list.OrderBy(o=>o.ParentKey , new MyComparer());



public class MyComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
{     
    public int Compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2)
    {
        if (ol.HasValue && o2.HasValue)
        {
            if (ol.ParentKey.Value == o2.ParentKey.Value)
                 return 0;
            return ol.ParentKey.Value  > o2.ParentKey.Value  ? 1 : -1;
        }
        else
            return 0;

    }
}
```

this will generate exact your expecting sequence

Comment: what is the result? you can make some change in Compare class to get your expected result.have you tried that?

Comment: i have edited code lately. check to see if used the last change.

Comment: this will not work...ones with the null will all be in the top...and 1 and 2 that was not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to achieve here is a [DFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first) ordered print of a tree.
Linq can't help you with that (at least out of the box).

I'd suggest adapting a DFS implementation to your data structure. See [Eric Lippert's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806795/687857).