# Filter an hierarchy list and keep the path

Tags: c#, hierarchy, depth-first-search

In C#, how can i search a hierarchy list and also keep the path intact at the end. For example:

**The object**

```
public class Node
{
    public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

**Result**

- a

  - aa

    - aaa
    - aab
- b

  - ba
  - bb

    - bba

**What i want**

If i search this list for the word "aab", i would like to show this result to the client:

- a

  - aa

    - aab

One implementation that i've found to search a hierarchy list is this one taken there https://stackoverflow.com/a/30907231/316759 but the problem is that it only return the leaf nodes found without keeping the hierarchy structure.

```
public static T DepthFirstSearch<T, TChilds>(this T node, Func<T, TChilds> ChildsProperty, Predicate<T> Match) where T : class
{
    Stack<T> stack = new Stack<T>();
    stack.Push(node);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        T thisNode = stack.Pop();

        if (Match(thisNode))
        {
            return thisNode;
        }

        if (ChildsProperty(thisNode) != null)
        {
            foreach (T child in (ChildsProperty(thisNode) as IEnumerable<T>).Reverse())
            {
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

What i need is to find leaf nodes and keep their parents to the root.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with the LINQ tree search? Got code?

Comment: "DFS and keep path" is pretty standard interview question. It is not yet clear what you have problem with and what kind of solution you want someone wrote for you (probably one line LINQ with SlectMany would be too complicated and recursion not fun)...

Comment: @Vlad, they only find the nodes and flatten the result without keeping the hierarchy structure.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, i have updated my question. I also tried to search more about DFS but i don't find any example that keep the path to the root.

Comment: @AlexandreJobin I think your code is too optimized for initial attempt... Basic recursive DFS is much easier to get path from (see approximate code in my post). In your code you'd either keep (parent, child) pairs in the stack or have "Node.Parent" to collect path back.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example that will let you mark the nodes you want as shown:

```
public bool NodeOrChildrenMatch(Node n)
{
    if (IsMatch(n))
    {
        Show(n);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n.Children.Any(NodeOrChildrenMatch))
        {
            Show(n);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approximate code - collect "path" while going down recursively and clean up last element while going up:

```
Stack<T> path = new Stack<T>();
public static bool DepthFirstSearch(T node, Stack<T> path, Predicate<T> Match) 
{
    path.Push(node);

    if (Match(node))
        return true;

    foreach (T child in (thisNode.Children)
    {
         if (DepthFirstSearch(child, stack, Match))
              return true;
    }

    stack.Pop();
    return false;
}
```